# how do I register a transform in ember-data rev 11?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For example, to register a type `raw` in an older version, I would have done something like this:

```
DS.attr.transform.raw = {
    from: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },
    to: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
}
```

How would I do this in the latest version of ember-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it looks in Rev 11:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('raw', {
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },  
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me on Rev 13:

```
DS.JSONTransforms.array = {
  serialize: function(value) {
    return Em.isNone(value) ? [] : value ;
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return Em.isNone(value) ? [] : value ;
  }
} ;
```